# Check if inputs form are empty jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

How can I check in jQuery if inputs with name denominationcomune_{{loop.index}} and denominationcomune_{{loop.index}} are empty not all inputs ?

I have a twig like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% for mat in mat_temp_array %}
        <input type="text" name="nomentite_{{loop.index}}"/>
        <input type="text" name="denominationcomune_{{loop.index}}" value="{{ mat.denominationcommun }}"/>
        <input type="text" name="denominationcomerce_{{loop.index}}" value="{{ mat.denominationcomerce }}"/>
    {% endfor %}

     <input type="submit" class="btn" value="save"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var empty = true;
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
   if ($(this).val() != "") {
      empty = false;
      return false;
   }
});
```

This should look all the input and set the empty var to false, if at least one is not empty.

**EDIT:**

To match the OP edit request, [this](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) can be used to filter input based on name substring.

`$('input[name*="denominationcomune_"]').each(...`

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this :

```
bool areFieldEmpty = YES;
//Label to leave the loops
outer_loop;

//For each input (except of submit) in your form
$('form input[type!=submit]').each(function(){
   //If the field's empty
   if($(this).val() != '')
   {
      //Mark it
      areFieldEmpty = NO;
      //Then leave all the loops
      break outer_loop;
   }
});

//Then test your bool
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using simple jQuery loop.

Total code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
select,textarea,input[type="text"],input[type="password"],input[type="datetime"],input[type="datetime-local"],input[type="date"],input[type="month"],input[type="time"],input[type="week"],input[type="number"],input[type="email"],input[type="url"],input[type="search"],input[type="tel"],input[type="color"],.uneditable-input{display:inline-block;height:20px;padding:4px;margin-bottom:9px;font-size:13px;line-height:18px;color:#555555;}
textarea{height:auto;}
select,textarea,input[type="text"],input[type="password"],input[type="datetime"],input[type="datetime-local"],input[type="date"],input[type="month"],input[type="time"],input[type="week"],input[type="number"],input[type="email"],input[type="url"],input[type="search"],input[type="tel"],input[type="color"],.uneditable-input{background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #cccccc;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);-webkit-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;-moz-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;-ms-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;-o-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;}textarea:focus,input[type="text"]:focus,input[type="password"]:focus,input[type="datetime"]:focus,input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,input[type="date"]:focus,input[type="month"]:focus,input[type="time"]:focus,input[type="week"]:focus,input[type="number"]:focus,input[type="email"]:focus,input[type="url"]:focus,input[type="search"]:focus,input[type="tel"]:focus,input[type="color"]:focus,.uneditable-input:focus{border-color:rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);outline:0;outline:thin dotted \9;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);height: 20px;}
select,input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{margin:3px 0;*margin-top:0;line-height:normal;cursor:pointer;}
select,input[type="submit"],input[type="reset"],input[type="button"],input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{width:auto;}
.uneditable-textarea{width:auto;height:auto;}
#country{height: 30px;}
.highlight
{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
</style>
<script>
function test()
{
var isFormValid = true;

$(".bs-example input").each(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        isFormValid = false;
        $(this).focus();
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
     }
    });

    if (!isFormValid) { 
    alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
}

return isFormValid;
}   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
<form onsubmit="return test()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a helper function like this

```
function checkWhitespace(inputString){

    let stringArray = inputString.split(' ');

    let output = true;

    for (let el of stringArray){
        if (el!=''){
            output=false;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Then check your input field value by passing through as an argument. If function returns **true**, that means value is only white space.

As an example

```
let inputValue = $('#firstName').val();
if(checkWhitespace(inputValue)) {
  // Show Warnings or return warnings
}else {
  // // Block of code-probably store input value into database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add an `class='denominationcomune'` to all elements that you want to check and then use the following:

```
function are_elements_emtpy(class_name)
{
  return ($('.' + class_name).filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ''; }).length == 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$('input[type="text"]').get().some(item => item.value !== '');

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      $(this).addClass('error');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
  });
});


<style>
 .error {
   border: 1px solid #ff0000;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Please add some written explanation to help OP and others who will visit your answer in near future as to what went wrong? and what it needed to fix that?

Comment: (!$(this).val()) this condition checks input filed having value or not its easy method to check whether input fields have value or not.